# I want to join two tables with a common column in Big query?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

To join the tables, I am using the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM(select user as uservalue1 FROM [projectname.FullData_Edited]) as FullData_Edited 
JOIN (select user as uservalue2 FROM [projectname.InstallDate]) as InstallDate 
ON FullData_Edited.uservalue1=InstallDate.uservalue2;
```

The query works but the joined table only has two columns uservalue1 and uservalue2.
I want to keep all the columns present in both the table. Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT <list of fields to output>
FROM [projectname:datasetname.FullData_Edited] AS FullData_Edited
JOIN [projectname:datasetname.InstallDate] AS InstallDate
ON FullData_Edited.user = InstallDate.user
```

or  (and preferable)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT <list of fields to output>
FROM `projectname.datasetname.FullData_Edited` AS FullData_Edited
JOIN `projectname.datasetname.InstallDate` AS InstallDate
ON FullData_Edited.user = InstallDate.user
```

Note, using `SELECT *` in such cases lead to `Ambiguous column name` error, so it is better  to put explicit list of columns/fields you need to have in your output

The way around it is in using [`USING()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using-clause) syntax as in example below.
Assuming that `user` is the ONLY ambiguous field  - it does the trick

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `projectname.datasetname.FullData_Edited` AS FullData_Edited
JOIN `projectname.datasetname.InstallDate` AS InstallDate
USING (user)
```

For example:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `projectname.datasetname.FullData_Edited` AS (
  SELECT 1 user, 'a' field1
),
`projectname.datasetname.InstallDate` AS (
  SELECT 1 user, 'b' field2
)
SELECT *
FROM `projectname.datasetname.FullData_Edited` AS FullData_Edited
JOIN `projectname.datasetname.InstallDate` AS InstallDate
USING (user)
```

returns

```sql
user    field1  field2   
1       a       b
```

whereas using `ON FullData_Edited.user = InstallDate.user` gives below error

`Error: Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): user`

Comment: And what about if it is not the only ambiguous filed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subqueries if you want all columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM [projectname.FullData_Edited] as FullData_Edited JOIN
     [projectname.InstallDate] as InstallDate 
     ON FullData_Edited.uservalue1 = InstallDate.uservalue2;
```

You may have to list out the particular columns you want to avoid duplicate column names.

While you are at it, you should also switch to standard SQL.

Comment: @VSR . . . Note the part of the answer that reads:  "You may have to list out the particular columns you want to avoid duplicate column names."